# EF and C#: How to save child data in loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i have three class called customer, address and contact. a single customer may have multiple address and a single address may have multiple contacts.

### see my class structure

```
public class CustomerBase
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Fax { get; set; }

}

public class Customer : CustomerBase
{
    public virtual List<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Addresses
{
    [Key]
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Contacts> Contacts { get; set; }

    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Contacts
{
    [Key]
    public int ContactID { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }

    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public virtual Addresses Customer { get; set; } 

}
```

address and contacts class has serial no field whose value will be like 1, 2 or 3 so on but based on customer or address id.

customer id 1 may have multiple address and each address serial no will be 1,2,3 etc again customer id 2 may have multiple address and each address serial no will be 1,2,3 etc again.

i can not make that field auto number because two customer address serial no may have same value.

if i save this way at a time to insert customer and their multiple address and each address has its own contact like below way then how could i specify value for serial no. see my sample code.

```
using (var db = new TestDBContext())
            {
                var customer = new Customer
                {
                    FirstName = "Test Customer1",
                    LastName = "Test Customer1",
                    Addresses = new List<Addresses>
                    {
                        new Addresses
                        {
                            Address1 = "test add1",
                            Address2 = "test add2",
                            IsDefault=true,
                            Contacts =  new List<Contacts>
                            {
                               new Contacts {  Phone = "1111111", Fax = "1-1111111",IsDefault=true },
                               new Contacts {  Phone = "2222222", Fax = "1-2222222",IsDefault=false  }
                            }
                        },
                        new Addresses
                        {
                            Address1 = "test add3",
                            Address2 = "test add3",
                            IsDefault=true,
                            Contacts =  new List<Contacts>
                            {
                               new Contacts {  Phone = "33333333", Fax = "1-33333333",IsDefault=false },
                               new Contacts {  Phone = "33333333", Fax = "1-33333333",IsDefault=true  }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                };

                db.Customer.Add(customer);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

if there is a way to specify manually value for serial no then please share the knowledge with code example.

i think i have to insert child records in loop. first i need to insert customer and hold inserted customer id and then query the address table with customer id for any data exist in address table for that customer id. if not then insert address details in loop and assign serial no manually and increment in loop. if customer already exist in address table for a specific customer then i have to get max serial no value and again insert details in loop and assign serial no = max serial no +1.

please guide me how to get over this problem because i am not good in EF. thanks

Comment: How can you save a field without defining it in the model? EntityFramework is an ORM, M => mapping. You need to define the serials no in the model, and assign it in your logic layer before sending to EF.

Comment: I don't see the point in an Address serial. An auto-incrementing address ID will allow sorting, and `Customers.Addresses.Count()` will give you the total number. Can you elaborate why you need it?

Comment: I have done something similar but I ended up to using database triggers, This gets complicated if you allow hard deletes. You need to know do you recycle the serials or to do have a missing number or do you just renumber all the addresses? If you have concurrent users setting this in the logic layer gets interesting as well.

Comment: @Mou instead of you managing the serial no in db, When you read the data back for display, just update the serial number on specific orderby criteria and show it.

Answer (score 0):

i have done the job this way.

```
    using (var db = new TestDBContext())
    {
        var customer = new Customer
        {
            FirstName = "Test Customer1",
            LastName = "Test Customer1",

        };

        db.Customer.Add(customer);
        db.SaveChanges();
        int CustomerID = customer.CustomerID;

        Addresses oAdr = new Addresses();
        oAdr.Address1 = "test add1";
        oAdr.Address2 = "test add2";
        oAdr.IsDefault = true;
        oAdr.CustomerID = CustomerID;
        oAdr.SerialNo = 1;
        db.Addresses.Add(oAdr);
        db.SaveChanges();
        int AddressID = oAdr.AddressID;

        Contacts oContacts = new Contacts();
        oContacts.Phone = "1111111";
        oContacts.Fax = "1-1111111";
        oContacts.SerialNo = 1;
        oContacts.IsDefault = true;
        oContacts.AddressID = AddressID;
        db.Contacts.Add(oContacts);
        db.SaveChanges();

        oContacts = new Contacts();
        oContacts.Phone = "222222222";
        oContacts.Fax = "2-1111111";
        oContacts.SerialNo = 2;
        oContacts.IsDefault = false;
        oContacts.AddressID = AddressID;
        db.Contacts.Add(oContacts);
        db.SaveChanges();

        oAdr = new Addresses();
        oAdr.Address1 = "test add3";
        oAdr.Address2 = "test add3";
        oAdr.SerialNo = 2;
        oAdr.IsDefault = false;
        oAdr.CustomerID = CustomerID;
        db.Addresses.Add(oAdr);
        db.SaveChanges();
        AddressID = oAdr.AddressID;

        oContacts = new Contacts();
        oContacts.Phone = "33333333";
        oContacts.Fax = "3-1111111";
        oContacts.IsDefault = true;
        oContacts.SerialNo = 1;
        oContacts.AddressID = AddressID;
        db.Contacts.Add(oContacts);
        db.SaveChanges();

        oContacts = new Contacts();
        oContacts.Phone = "444444444";
        oContacts.Fax = "4-1111111";
        oContacts.SerialNo = 2;
        oContacts.IsDefault = false;
        oContacts.AddressID = AddressID;
        db.Contacts.Add(oContacts);
        db.SaveChanges();

    }
```